# Traducir "overview" al español

Tags: traducción, uso-de-palabras

En las tiendas virtuales frecuentemente se muestran listados de productos con información resumida. Luego pinchando en cierto producto se dirige a la pagina de la ficha del producto, donde se detalla la información. En inglés se puede llamar el listado "overview". ¿Hay un término equivalente en español?

Comment: "Reseña" es frecuente. No lo agrego como respuesta porque no es totalmente correcto.

Answer (score 3):

En español he visto ese tipo de fichas con las siguientes denominaciones:

"Detalle" ó "Ficha de detalle"

"Resumen" (no tiene mucho sentido si es una ficha con todos los datos, pero sí si muestra los principales)

"Información"

...

Comment: **Resumen** (no _resúmen_) me parecería la más adecuada, a falta de una palabra más precisa.

Comment: Yo suelo usar 'vista general' o 'revisión general‘

Answer (score 1):

Yo diría que el termino que buscas podría ser "Vista general", así como "Preview" es "Vista previa".